how to make start of 'align*' material line up with start of preceding line of text?
I use an \hskip command in an align* environment to make it be left-aligned with the start of the preceding line of text. However, obtaining the skip value requires trial and error. Is there better way to handle this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

5. beam section: $b\times h=200\text{ mm}\times400\text{ mm}$

\vskip-20pt
\begin{align*}\text{beam weight: }
      g_3&=200\times400\times25\times10^{-6}\hskip108pt \\
         &=2\text{ kN/m$^2$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}



You should really use the siunitx package to format units. Not \text that command does not do what you thing it does. And a word space before units  is wrong

Is “5.” the result of an \item instruction in an enumerate environment?

vskip is used to reduce vertical space

"5." is not the result of \item  . it's a regualar text.

@Mico  thank you for editing .

@XCN As I specified in my answer, the code from $\begin{aligned}[t] up to \end{aligned}$ can be used anywhere.

I suggest you employ a \phantom directive to place "beam weight" below "beam section", and an aligned[t] environment instead of an align* environment. Oh, and please make a habit of using  the \qty and \unit macros of the siunitx package to typeset quantities and their associated scientific units.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % for '\qty' macro

\begin{document}

5. beam section: $b\times h=\qty{200}{mm}\times \qty{400}{mm}$

\smallskip % optional
\phantom{5. }beam weight: 
$\begin{aligned}[t]
    g_3&=200\times400\times25\times10^{-6} \\
       &=\qty{2}{\kilo\newton\per\meter\squared}
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}


I guess you're doing an enumerate, but the trick below is independent on the environment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc
\item ddd
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
        &\text{beam section: }b\times h=\qty{200}{mm}\times\qty{400}{mm} \\
        &\begin{aligned}
         \text{beam weight: }
         g_3 &= 200\times400\times25\times10^{-6} \\
             &=\qty{2}{kN/m^2}
         \end{aligned}
      \end{aligned}$
\item fff
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


If you try
5. $\begin{aligned}[t]
        &\text{beam section: }b\times h=\qty{200}{mm}\times\qty{400}{mm} \\
        &\begin{aligned}
         \text{beam weight: }
         g_3 &= 200\times400\times25\times10^{-6} \\
             &=\qty{2}{kN/m^2}
         \end{aligned}
      \end{aligned}$

you get essentially the same output. No clumsy phantoms and code duplication.
A better layout for enumerate:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc
\item ddd
\item beam section: $b\times h=\qty{200}{mm}\times\qty{400}{mm}$

      beam weight:
      $\begin{aligned}[t]
        g_3 &= 200\times400\times25\times10^{-6} \\
            &= \qty{2}{kN/m^2}
      \end{aligned}$
\item fff
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}



The OP actually wrote in a comment below their main posting, "5. is not the result of \item. it's a regualar text". Of course, your first solution approach doesn't depend on an enumerate environment being used.

@Mico Apparently the OP isn’t able to read my answer, where I clearly state that the trick is completely independent on enumerate

@egreg  when I insert \setlength{\itemindent}{-7pt}  after \begin{enumerate} ,  beam section:   and beam weight:   left start positions are not same any more. can this be fixed ?

In other words, how to move the whole enumerate content horizontally ?

@XCN Avoiding silly instructions such as setting the item indent to a negative value. Didn't you say that this is not in an enumerate?

Yes , after reading your code, I decide to use enumerate instead,  but I want to change enumerate  horizontal position . \setlength{\itemindent}{} can work, but it changes item relative position.

@XCN Reading the manual of enumitem might help you.

Just use \begin{enumerate}[left=9pt,topsep=10pt]  . I once used these settings but  it did't work last time.
